# wpf render gui async

Tags: wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, render

i got an `ItemsControl` with an `Expander` in it and in the `Expander` are a view `ProgressBars` inclued. My problem is when i am loading the data (which is not my performance problem) and then i update PropertyChanged of my `ItemSource` my gui freezes for a long time cuz it needs so long to render.

Is there a way i can redner the gui elements async so that my gui doesnt freeze???
I already searched a bit, though im not sure if my search results solve my problem.
So i am asking here, hoping for a nice solution.

They gui does look something like this.. though there are usually more elements
[image] you all can imageine the xaml code behind...

```
private void RefreshOverview(){
        ...
        foreach (Characteristic c in characteristics)
        {
            Area a = c.Area;

            Characteristic c1 = c;
            foreach (Line l in lines.Where(l => l.Product.Id == c1.Product.Id))
            {
                List<IMeasurementSchedule> measurementSchedules;
                // take DefaultMeasurementSchedules if exists
                if (c.DefaultMeasurementSchedules == null || c.DefaultMeasurementSchedules.Count == 0)
                    measurementSchedules = new List<IMeasurementSchedule>(l.LineMeasurementSchedules.ToArray());
                else
                    measurementSchedules = new List<IMeasurementSchedule>(c.DefaultMeasurementSchedules.ToArray());

                foreach (IMeasurementSchedule ms in measurementSchedules)
                {
                    MeasureCharacteristic mc;
                    if (a.PeripheryEnabled)
                    {
                        Line l1 = l;
                        foreach (AreaItem ai in areaitems.Where(x => x.AreaId == a.Id && x.LineId == l1.Id))
                        {
                            mc = (from cm in _context.CharacteristicMeasures.Local
                                  where cm.Charge == null &&
                                        cm.Characteristic.Id == c.Id &&
                                        cm.Line.Id == l.Id &&
                                        cm.ShiftIndex.Id == actualShiftIndex.Id &&
                                        cm.AreaItem != null &&
                                        cm.AreaItem.Id == ai.Id &&
                                        cm.MeasureScheduleId == ms.Id
                                  select cm).FirstOrDefault() ??
                                 new MeasureCharacteristic
                                     {
                                         Characteristic = c,
                                         Line = l,
                                         ShiftIndex = actualShiftIndex,
                                         AreaItem = ai
                                     };
                            mc.MeasureSchedule = ms;
                            characteristicsMeasures.Add(AddMeasures(mc));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mc = (from cm in _context.CharacteristicMeasures.Local
                              where cm.Charge == null &&
                                    cm.Characteristic.Id == c.Id &&
                                    cm.Line.Id == l.Id &&
                                    cm.ShiftIndex.Id == actualShiftIndex.Id &&
                                    cm.MeasureScheduleId == ms.Id
                              select cm).FirstOrDefault() ??
                             new MeasureCharacteristic {Characteristic = c, Line = l, ShiftIndex = actualShiftIndex};
                        mc.MeasureSchedule = ms;
                        characteristicsMeasures.Add(AddMeasures(mc));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MeasureCharacteristics = characteristicsMeasures;
        MeasureCharacteristicsByType =
            CharacteristicMeasureGroupedByType.GetExpanderViewProductItems(characteristicsMeasures);
    }
```

thats my code ;) MeasureCharacteristicsByType is a `IEnumerable<CharacteristicMeasureGroupedByType>` i do bind my itemsource to. if you need more information just ask!!!

**UPDATE**

here is my link to my xaml code..
http://pastebin.com/UA777LjW

Comment: You won't be able to render visual elements in a different thread that the main GUI thread. We need to see your code to suggest some workarounds.

Comment: just updated my post.. if you need more info then just ask isntead of downvoting ;)

Comment: FYI, it's not me that have downvoted. Moreover we need the XAML to understand where bindings are.

Comment: sry i wasnt blaming u..  i've added a link to my xaml code.. not the readability but still...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing logic to build your data and rendering operations.
Isolate the one from the other to identify which is taking time.

For example don't affect `MeasureCharacteristicsByType` in the same for loop as the linq queries. 
Then measure times with a `StopWatch` instance.

If the rendering takes the most time, insert the items in the `MeasureCharacteristicsByType` one by one (not at the same time), with this kind of instruction to render them one after the other :

```
foreach(var charMeasureByType in CharacteristicMeasureGroupedByType.GetExpanderViewProductItems(characteristicsMeasures))
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<OneTypeHere>((OneTypeHere item) =>
    {
       MeasureCharacteristicsByType.Add(item)
    }), DispatcherPriority.Background, charMeasureByType);
}
```

Edit : `OneTypeHere` is the type of `charMeasureByType`.

Comment: i've already analysed which part is taking the most time.. the rendering does... i'll try to implement it your way. only to check if i've understood: just get the data in a background thread.. and add the items via dispatcher one by one ?!

Comment: I've just completed my sample.

Comment: i dont get it.. i get the error 'Cannot access non-static method 'BeginInvoke' in static context.

Comment: Because the code assume that you're in a DependencyObject element (like a UIElement). If you're not in a UIElement, try : `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`

Comment: yep you're right. this was the probleme. know i've implemented your code and i am adding the items one by one... still my gui freezes.. if i run my method `RefreshOverview` in another thread the gui doesnt update my itemcontrol at all.. :( though everytime i press the refresh button i get the following message in the output window `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll`